# Python: How to print element from an array that starts with a specific number using Regex?

Tags: python

I have a file with some data:

```
Dave Martin
615-555-7164
173 Main St., Springfield RI 55924
davemartin@bogusemail.com

Charles Harris
800-555-5669
969 High St., Atlantis VA 34075
charlesharris@bogusemail.com

Eric Williams
560-555-5153
806 1st St., Faketown AK 86847
laurawilliams@bogusemail.com
```

Next, I read the lines of the file and want to store all elements of that list that start with my specific number, into a new list.

```
from os import sep
import re

number = int(input("Number: "))
last_digit = number % 10
final = str(last_digit)

results = []

with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
desired = lines[2::5]

results = re.findall('^[4][0-9]{2}$', desired)

print(results)
```

I don't know how to put my number in Regex, for now it's 4...

But I always get this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

***SOLVED***

```
from os import sep
import re

number = int(input("Number: "))
last_digit = number % 10
final = str(last_digit)

results = []

with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
desired = lines[2::5]

r = re.compile("[" + re.escape(final) + "][0-9]{2}.*")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, desired))

print("********************")
print(*newlist)
```

Comment: Your regular expression is currently saying: find me a string that starts with 4 following by 2 numbers between 0 and 9 which ends the string.
Try this: "^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}[\t\n ]*$" <- This looks for three sets of numbers separated by dashes possibly ending with whitespace or a line return.

Comment: Side question: Is the variable desired actually set? I'm unfamiliar with the expression lines[2::5]

Comment: @RMiller desired is an array that takes elements from lines[] with [start:end:step], that's unimportant for my problem. Using ur Regex expression, the error still persists. I think it is a python error, not due regex

Comment: `desired` is a list, not a string. Try `re.findall('^[4][0-9]{2}$', '\n'.join(desired), re.M)`

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is related to fact, that your regex work over list and not string or bytes-like object.

Doing `"\n".join(desired)` will remove error, but regex have to be run with `re.M` flag to support multiline.